# Get variables from included file

Tags: php, variables, include, require-once

How do I use variables from an included file, and use it for other included files as well?

**index**

```
<?php
$tmp = new template($connect);
$tmp->globals('index');
$logged_in = false; //works in all included files
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php $tmp->template('head'); ?> //class method to include file
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $description; ?> //does not work either
```

**include_head.php**

```
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>//does not echo anything
```

**index_globals.php**

```
<?php
    $title="title";
    $description="description";   
 ?>
```

**How I am including**

```
public function template($file){
    if(isset($file) && file_exists($this->dir.$file.".php")){
        ob_start();
        include($this->dir.$file.".php");
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        return $template;
     }
}
```

**Globals Function**

```
public function globals($name){
  if(isset($name) && file_exists($this->dir.$name."_globals.php")){
      include($this->dir.$name."_globals.php");
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you including the files?

Comment: Have you tried `echo $GLOBALS['title']`? Same goes for `$description`. There's a special section in the [documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Comment: see update. I'll try the `$GLOBALS` method now --- that method did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "import" the globals by returning an array instead of declaring the variables:

```
<?php
// index_globals.php

return [
    'title' => 'title',
    'description' => 'description',
];
```

Then, from the `globals()` function you import it into a local property:

```
private $context = [];

public function globals($name)
{
    if (isset($name) && file_exists($this->dir.$name."_globals.php")) {
        $this->context = include($this->dir.$name."_globals.php");
    }
}
```

Finally, update the `template()` method:

```
public function template($file)
{
    if (isset($file) && file_exists($this->dir.$file.".php")) {
        extract($this->context);
        ob_start();
        include($this->dir.$file.".php");
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        return $template;
     }
}
```

Note that your index will not have access to `$description` in this case either, but it shouldn't be hard to gain access via the `template` instance.

Comment: I edited your code you used `[]` when it should be `array()`. Other than that it worked like a charm!

Comment: @EasyBB The `[]` syntax has been around since 5.4, it's time to upgrade :)

Comment: PHP version 5.2.*  damn 000webhost. Good thing I only use them for testing purposes and not to host my actual websites haa. Thank you so much Jack. You've helped me, plus you've taught me a very good little lesson here! Can't explain my appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the variables into a stored property.

```
$tmp->set(array(
    'title' => 'hello world',
    'description' => 'this is the value'
));

// Or set a single value
$tmp->set('myCoolVariable', 'this is another value');
```

Implementation:

```
class template {
     protected $vars = array();

     public function set($key, $value)
     {
         if (is_array($key)) {
             // merge into existing
             $this->vars = array_merge($this->vars, $key);
         } else {
             // set a new variable with the name $key and value as $value
             $this->vars[$key] = $value;
         }
     }
}
```

Then in your output buffer method, `extract()` the stored variables

```
public function template($file)
{
    if (isset($file) && file_exists($this->dir.$file.".php")) {
        ob_start();
        extract($this->vars); // extract it so it is available for the current buffer
        include($this->dir.$file.".php");
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean(); // don't forget to clean and turn it off
        return $template;
     }
}
```

Comment: So this would work between two different files? Say index.php and *_globals.php?

Answer (score 0):

When you include a file in PHP using `include()` or `require()` or something that brings that file into another, the included file is basically embedded into the file including it. It's like writing all the code from the included file into the file calling `include(*file*)`.

Simply put: When you include a file, all of it's variables are able to be used like any other variable declared if you successfully include it with `include()`, `require()`, or something like the mentioned methods.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that but it's not working for myself. I've also tested to see if that file is actually being parsed and it is